# What is the proper way of implementing Table Data Gateway pattern in Zend Framework 1.x?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db-table

According to Zend quick start guide I need three classes (A model, A mapper class and a table gateway class) to implement the Table Data Gateway pattern. But is this a good approach?

Right now this is how I implement the pattern.

```
class Application_Model_Person(){
    private $_name;

    public function getName();
    public function setName($name);
}   

class Application_Model_PersonMapper extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {

      public function fetch();
      public function search();
      public function save(Application_Model_Person $person);
      public function delete();

}
```

So I have a model class with all getter/setter methods and another class which extends the Zend_Db_Table_Abstract class and performs all crud operations. I like this approach as it reduces the number of classes and is easy to follow. But is this a proper way of doing it?

Also what advantages will I get if I use the approach in the Zend quick start guide?

Comment: This isn't really about Zend's Quick start guide but common practice. You want to read Martin Fowler's blog and his links are in many places in the Zend docu. Here's a starting point to [Table Data Gateway](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html)

Comment: I do understand the pattern, and your right it's not about the quick start guide either. My reference to quick start guide was just to highlight one of the approaches used to implement this pattern. In my question I have also highlighted another such approach which I use. My question is that are there any other approaches to implement this pattern? and which one is the best? as this is a pattern it can be coded using different approaches....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the size of your project really. ZF is what I call "enterprise ready", i.e. build a large web application. In my mind and following these pattern I can scale almost infinitely. However, for many smaller projects this could be overkill.

The only problem I see with your example is extending a mapper to a DbTable which is following the common pattern just wrong. For a smaller project you could have your Models (external--application view) and access your DbTable classes (internal--Db gateway) directly and skip the mapper.

If for whatever reason later on you decide you need mappers for certain tables you should be able to implement them rather easily.